How to disable request example JSON formatting in Swagger
I'm writing an C# .NET 8 application using OpenAPI and Swagger.
I've a specific endpoint, where the defined JSON request example needs to have a specific format. In my case it's slimmed in one line without any indent, line breaks etc.
Looking into the swagger.json is all good, but when Swagger UI reads this request example it gets pretty printet (reformatted) in the UI and when executing the request, it has been changed compared to the example defined using OpenAPI in Swagger.json.
Are there any way that I can disable this?
The reason is, that the endpoints is an GitHub Webhook endpoint. The example should emulate the request from GitHub keeping the exact JSON/body format. Because the payload is hashed using a shared secret and compared with a provided signature header, the validation mechanism does no longer accept the incoming request.

It's unclear why you want this. Github will call the API, not the UI. The Swagger UI is an optional component only meant to make it easier to view the Swagger schema and make some simple test calls. Typically it's only enabled in Development environments

If you want to test the API's behavior, use curl, Postman, an .http file  or REST Client to send test requests exactly how you want them and check the responses

I know that Swagger UI is optional, but I would like to use it and have valid request examples for documentation purposes.

provide examples of what you tried and your expected output
